# Why am I having a 1064 error in my SQL syntax?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Database error 1064 while doing query You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(subject,message,textmessage,entered, status) values("subject test"," html test"' at line 1

```
$result= Sql_query("insert into {$tables['messsage']} 
(subject,message,textmessage,entered, status) values(\"subject 
test\",\" html test\",\"text message test\",now(),\"draft\")");
```

Comment: `values(\"subject 
test\",\" html test\",\"text message test\",now(),\"draft\")")` Where these values are coming from? This is not valid to insert into database.

Comment: Something is wrong with your table name.

Comment: you are right @GordonLinoff. It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

The 1064 error can have multiple causes.
First of all: "sql_query" is pointing on your own function? If not you must change it with "mysql_query".
Anyway, you can check if all fields have the right type settings: varchar, text, datetime, timestamp, int...

Assuming that $tables['messsage'] is correct, you can try to change your code adding the char ` to table name:

```
$result = Sql_query("INSERT INTO `{$tables['messsage']}` (subject,message,textmessage,entered,status) VALUES (\"subject 
test\",\"html test\",\"text message test\",now(),\"draft\")");
```

Hope it helps.